# How to open up emoji keyboard in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, emoji, android-jetpack-compose

I've been trying to figure out how to open up the emoji keyboard in Jetpack Compose. Since there is no specific `KeyboardType` instance for emojis in order for us to use as input type in `TextField` which would be awesome if they had in the first place in Compose. I don't want to use custom emoji keyboard solutions like [Emoji](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji) or [SuperNova-Emoji](https://github.com/hani-momanii/SuperNova-Emoji) unless I don't find any other native Compose solution. Do you guys know how to achieve this in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: You cannot achieve it inside or outside of Compose. You cannot force users to have a keyboard that offers emojis. And, even if they do, you cannot force a keyboard into an emoji mode.

Comment: Even though, Android does not support showing emoji keyboard as input type. I believe that it makes sense to provide an emoji as input type in the traditional `EditText` or Compose's `TextField`. It feels like Jetpack Compose or any other new or existing Android APIs should offer this functionality for us to use in our apps since emoji usage accelerated in recent years.  Enabling emoji as an input type removes the burden of creating custom solutions for a simple problem that is so resolvable just by adding it. I hope, Google would make this minor functionality in their future API updates.