# I working on a chat app but I dont know how i can add emoji panel to the keypad in android compose

Tags: android, kotlin, view, android-jetpack-compose, emoji

@Composable
fun ChatEditText(

```
text: String,
onValueChange: (newValue: String) -> Unit
```

) {

```
TextField(
    colors =TextFieldDefaults.colors(
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        focusedContainerColor = Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
        unfocusedContainerColor = Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
    ),
    maxLines = 10,
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        onValueChange(it)
    },
    placeholder = { Text("Type a message") },
    trailingIcon = {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.emoji),
            contentDescription = "Insert emoticon",
            tint = Color(0xff808080)
        )
    },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(40.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(248.dp),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
        imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,

    )


)
```

}

saw some solution in view (xml) but i dont know how i can use it with with compose functions, as my project is purely in compose. i guess it will work if i can get this successfully  val emojiPopup = EmojiPopup(rootView, emojiEditText), but couldnt find the views despite creating the files and calling them in the main activity. the rootView is to calculate the size of the keypad according to the vanniktech.emoji documentation which in this case will mean i could create a layout file. Im using a ChatScreen compsable with  a lazy column showing the chats based on whether the chat is a receiverChat or a SenderChat and arrange accordingly on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this seems to not be possible inside or outside of compose. The best you can do is open a regular text keyboard where the user has the option of opening the emoji part.

[Duplicate of this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68913913/how-to-open-up-emoji-keyboard-in-jetpack-compose)